# Avoid idle page after fork

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, zend-framework

After really a lot of efforts i have managed to get my php Zend application run with  multithreading. To do so i have configured Apache in CGI mode in order to use php pcntl_* functions.
I have this issue
This is my fork

```
    function fork() {
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if ($pid == -1)
        throw new Exception('fork error on Task object');
    elseif ($pid) {
        # we are in parent class
        $this->pid = $pid;
        # echo "< in parent with pid {$his->pid}\n";
    } else {
        # we are in child
        $sid = posix_setsid();
        if ($sid < 0) {
            exit;
        }
        $this->run();
    }
}
```

each time i call this function, process is created and it run flawlessly but i lost the control of the webpage on the browser (i cannot navigate through my website anymore). It seems to load the page for a long time until it gives me an error.
I need to shut down the browser (with simply a new tab I can't reconnect) and then reconnect to the server.
Could it be that the last created process is listening on my http port? How can i solve this?
Thanks

Comment: Your parent process does nothing, and your child process never exists. Parent can't obtain the control since the child never exited (what does `$this->run();` do anyway?), and there is no output returned to the Apache which probably terminates the connection after not receiving any data. On the other hand, this is not multithreading and it's kind of pointless to fork the process handling web page delivery.

Comment: @N.B. `it's kind of pointless to fork the process handling web page delivery` - I don't know, sometimes I *like* to make things more difficult than they need to be. Keeps life interesting.

Comment: What makes you think the child process never exits? The only way a PHP process can fail to exit is if there's an infinite loop somewhere, which certainly isn't shown here. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a session-locking issue to me - whenever you call `session_start()`, PHP takes an exclusive lock on the session file on disk, so that two PHP pages can't write conflicting information to the same session. If you call `session_start()` while that lock is in place, it will "hang" until the process locking the session finished (or calls `session_write_close()` or `session_destroy()`).

My guess is that before you "fork" your PHP process, you are opening a session (or perhaps taking some other exclusive lock) and this lock isn't being released properly, as PHP is not designed to be used in a multi-threaded (or, rather, multi-process) environment.

Rather than trying to get true forking to work under PHP, you're probably better off spawning a totally new PHP script with `system` or `exec`, and passing serialized data to it using a messaging framework such as `ZeroMQ`. That way, you can not only set the *initial conditions of the child* based on the parent, but actually *pass back information from the child*.

Don't forget, however, that the child process created in this way would be running under the "command-line SAPI", which may be subject to a different `php.ini`, and won't have a definition of things you normally take for granted like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

Comment: The actual problem is that child never exits. Parent and child processes can communicate, and there's also shared memory that's used for such purposes. Why would you make things more complex using ZeroMQ? It's not like you can learn how to use ZeroMQ in matter of a few hours.

Comment: Because it means you don't run into issues like this? Because Apache mod_php is the most efficient way of running PHP, and precludes messing about with OS threads? Because multi-threading is hard, but inter-process communication with ZeroMQ is easy?

Comment: if you are at the point where you **need** background parallel processing, then you won't fork the php process spawned by apache, you'll create a daemon that you'll talk to via ZeroMQ or IPC of your choice. Apache's mod_php definitely **_is_not_** the most efficient way of running PHP, since you're into ZeroMQ - take a look at [photon PHP framework](http://www.photon-project.com/). If you want to do things efficiently, then you should do them efficiently from the start.

Comment: Absolutely, a daemon would be even better. But if you want the ability to spawn ad hoc parallelism within your code, without a daemon needing prior knowledge of the environment each task requires, creating a command-line process on the fly can be useful - it works a bit like loading multiple sets of results onto a page via AJAX, where each response is just a normal PHP invocation.

Comment: Incidentally, my point about mod_php was that, as the OP mentions, allowing true forking in PHP generally means down-grading the entire server to run PHP under CGI.